# Would だれがいますか mean who is in or whose in this case?

Tags: particle-が

Here is my sentence of question このきょしつにだれがいますか . I believe it means, "Who is in this classroom?" although I read in my book (Genki 1) that it がいます could also mean that someone has something so would this instead mean, "Whose classroom is this?"

This whole がいますか and がありますか section (especially in question form) is giving me a rough time. I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: きょしつ should be きょうしつ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several clues:

- 'Whose' would have a possessive の: だれの.
- The verb would be です rather than います.
- The particle に is a clear indication that we are dealing with someone or something existing *in* the classroom.

'Whose classroom is this?' may be something like この[教]{きょう}[室]{しつ}は[誰]{だれ}のですか。